# Why am I getting a differently arranged output?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4stvR.jpg)

Why am I getting this difference in output upon using the print function.Also why is the ouput not matching the actual input in either of the cases?

Answer (score 2):

`sets` are unordered data types that's why you get different results.

Comment: Thank you. Can I  please know how should I overcome  this problem

Comment: instead of set you can use ordered data types like `list`, `tuple`, and so on.